# Importing files installed separately into Steam

Tags: steam

I already have Path of Exile downloaded and installed from their site. I'd like to add it as a Steam game so I can unlock the various Steam achievements while playing it.

However, Steam insists on downloading the entire several gigs - how do I get it to detect my existing files? I tried download and then cancel it, followed by moving my existing game directory under `steamapps/common` , but this didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

If you want the steam achievements, you'll need to use their version of the game.

Comment: Yes, but 'their version' is same as the base with a few other config files - seems stupid that I'd need to re-download everything.

Comment: They're most likely not the same version, especially because the Steam version includes the word "Steam" in it's executable name. Games on Steam can use it as a DRM and optionally have it encrypt the executable (and possibly more, and parts of the game data can be encrypted by the developers which could also effect the trick) because the partial download and cancel and replace with existing data trick does require that the existing data be the same version for it to work. You could try deleting the executable from your existing data, but most likely you will need to download the whole game.

Comment: It's obviously not the same because Steam can track in-game achievements.  The game has to somehow tell Steam your achievement progress for it to work, hence there's no way it is exactly the same.